# Como cancelar uma requisição http no interceptor?

Tags: angular, http-request, interceptor

Estou criando uma arquitetura para um projeto meu aqui e me surgiu a necessidade de cancelar uma requisição já dentro de um interceptor.

Basicamente eu preciso automatizar a solicitação de captcha e pretendo utilizar o interceptor para isso.

Alguém já passou por isso? Como poderia cancelar o request?

> Exemplo do interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { from, Observable, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { CaptchaService } from './shared/captcha/captcha.service';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private readonly captcha: CaptchaService
    ) {
    }

    async validacaoAssincrona(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
        let headers = req.headers;
        const tokenJwt = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN') ?? sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN');
        if(tokenJwt) {
            headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenJwt}`)
        }

        if(req.params.get('vc_captcha_operation')) {
            // verificando necessidade do captcha
            const tokenCaptcha = await this.captcha.checkBotUi(req.params.get('vc_captcha_operation'));
            if(!tokenCaptcha) {
                // cancelando request
                return { isRequestCancel: true };
            } else {
                headers = headers.set('x-captcha-token', tokenCaptcha);
            }
        }

        return { isRequestCancel: false, headers };
    }

    async intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return from(this.validacaoAssincrona(req))
            .pipe(switchMap((result: any) => {
                const authReq = req.clone({ headers: result.headers });
                if(result.isRequestCancel) {
                    // como cancelar?
                }

                return next.handle(authReq);
            }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Algumas respostas aqui no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433953/how-to-cancel-current-request-in-interceptor-angular-4). Testou alguma delas? Uma delas diz que vc pode retornar um `EMPTY ` do rxjs. Outra diz que você pode lançar uma exceção usando o `Observable`, como: `if (result.isRequestCancel) {
        return Observable.throw('...');
    }`. Teste alguma delas, caso não o tenha feito.

Comment: Não faz sentido algum as negativações na minha pergunta. Não achei nada parecido com ela aqui, poderiam ao menos informar o motivo de negativar. Pode ser algo óbvio? Pode! Mas eu pesquisei e não achei, por isso recorri ao SOpt. Outra coisa, eu coloquei o que eu necessitava, enviei o código que estou utilizando atualmente, não quebrei regra alguma da comunidade. Enfim... Poderiam informar o motivo da negativação!

Comment: @CmteCardeal muito obrigado! Deu certo, consegui chegar ao resultado graças ao seu comentário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graças há um comentário, consegui atingir o meu objetivo. Não entendi as negativações na pergunta, seria bom um comentário para falar o porque ela é "ruim" ou "negativa" para a comunidade. Deixo abaixo o meu problema solucionado, obrigado!

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { from, Observable, switchMap, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { CaptchaService } from './shared/captcha/captcha.service';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(
            private readonly captcha: CaptchaService
        ) {
        }
    
        async validacaoAssincrona(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
            let headers = req.headers;
            const tokenJwt = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN') ?? sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN');
            if(tokenJwt) {
                headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenJwt}`)
            }
    
            if(req.params.get('vc_captcha_operation')) {
                // verificando necessidade do captcha
                const tokenCaptcha = await this.captcha.checkBotUi(req.params.get('vc_captcha_operation'));
                if(!tokenCaptcha) {
                    // cancelando request
                    return { isRequestCancel: true };
                } else {
                    headers = headers.set('x-captcha-token', tokenCaptcha);
                }
            }
    
            return { isRequestCancel: false, headers };
        }
    
        async intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return from(this.validacaoAssincrona(req))
                .pipe(switchMap((result: any) => {
                    const authReq = req.clone({ headers: result.headers });
                    if(result.isRequestCancel) {
                        return throwError(() => 'O request foi cancelado pelo interceptor.');
                    }
    
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                }))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Traduzindo uma resposta do [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47254079/4825796).

Para cancelar uma requisição dentro do interceptor é so preciso interromper a linha de comunicação do interceptor.  Nós fazemos isso simplesmente por retornar um Observable vazio. Siga o Exemplo:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (stopThisRequest) {
    return EMPTY;
  }

  return next.handle(request);
}
```